# getting error while trying to open a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have written a C++ code to create some filenames inside a loop. For example, I will run the loop for eight times and create 8 text files like:

```
input0.txt, input1.txt,......., input7.txt
```

My sample code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

std::string to_string(int i) {
   std::stringstream s;
   s << i;
   return s.str();
} 

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;
    string fileName;
    string name1 = "input";
    string name2 = ".txt";
    while(i<=7)
    {
        fileName = name1+ to_string(i)+ name2;
        cout<<fileName<<"\n";
        fp=fopen(fileName,"r");
        i++;
     }

}
```

But, when I run the code, i am getting the following error:

```
 error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'FILE* fopen(const char*, const char*)'
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? What is the solution?

Comment: `fopen(filename.c_str(), "r")` will solve your problem.

Comment: **Use C++11**, I/O streams and you can delete your `to_string` implementation also.

Comment: Also, you do not have `#include <string>` in your code.  You're relying on the compiler's implementation to provide this header without you specifying it, and there is no guarantee that this header will be included.

Comment: If you want to use C I/O functions, you should also close the files in the while loop. Have you already tried all the snippets users posted in your previous questions?

Answer (score 4):

Just look at the error message you get.

`fopen()` takes a `const char*` not a `std::string` as a parameter. To get a `const char*` of your string use the `.c_str()` function.

fopen() though is a c-api. As an alternative you can also use the filestreams of c++.

`std::fstream` for read/write and `std::ifstream` for input only. `std::ofstream` for output only.

Answer (score 1):

- Erase your function to_string to use the one provided by std library and avoid conflict.
- Then convert std::string into char * using .c_str() when it is needed.
- Remove useless includes

Final code :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  FILE *fp;
  int i=0;
  string fileName;
  string name1 = "input";
  string name2 = ".txt";

  while(i <= 7)
  { 
    fileName = name1 + to_string(i).c_str() + name2;
    cout << fileName << "\n";
    fp=fopen(fileName.c_str(),"r");
    i++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::ofstream` instead of mixing C and C++.

```
int main()
{
    string file_name{ "input" };
    string extention{ ".txt" };

    for (int i{}; i != 8; ++i) {
        string temp_file_name{ file_name + to_string(i) + extention };
        ofstream file{ temp_file_name };
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of syntax is this, the initialisation with curly braces? Also, OP's code is wrong not because he's not using 'ofstream'.

Comment: @mbaitoff It's called [uniform initialization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/133690).